# Netbeans 8: нет возможности добавлять методы и поля  через пункты меню в панели Projects

Tags: java, netbeans

В одном пособии читаю про netbeans 5.5:
"Щелчок правой клавиши мышки в области надписи Methods и выбор пункта Add Method… всплывающего окна приводит к появлению диалога, в котором можно путем установки галочек и выбора пунктов выпадающего меню задавать нужные параметры метода".
И там еще картиночка, что это можно делать в панели Project.

http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/569/425/lecture/9667?page=8

Так у меня в панели Project под названиями файлов никаких пунктов меню, предлагающих выбрать компонент,  не появляется. И на правой кнопке мышки не появляется. На правой кнопке мыши (и то в самом тексте кода) можно только выбрать пункт insert code... conctructor.
А чтобы там fields или method - так нетути.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вы сами же и сказали, инструкция относится к Netbeans 5.5. Логично предположить, что к 8 версии она будет несколько устаревшей. Специально перепроверил, в Netbeans 8 нет диалога добавления нового метода. Есть только рефакторинг Introduce Method, который выносит часть кода из одного метода в другой. И это, в принципе, логично: программист гораздо быстрее создаст метод вручную, чем  если бы он отмечал кучу чекбоксов в диалоге. Поэтому этот функционал был удвлён как ненужный.

**Оффтопик**

Как же мне дороги преподаватили университетов с их паталогической любовью к всяческим визардам и диалогам! ИМХО, за приучение студентов к мышекликательному программированию нужно лишать диплома и отлучать от церкви. За привязку курса к конкретной IDE тоже. Мой вам совет: старайтесь на начальных этапах как можно меньше пользоваться инструментами IDE и как можно больше кода писать самостоятельно. Это поможет лучше осознать связь между вашими действиями и поведением программы. Впоследствии, когда вы будете чётко осознавать, зачем нужен каждый из инструментов автоматизации написания кода, можете смело пользоваться ими, но на ранних этапах ими лучше не злоупотреблять.